# Need to deploy angular app in customer premises and need to maintain integrity of application

Tags: angular, webserver

One of our applications needs to be deployed in the client environment over the intranet and we need to maintain the integrity of our application code. How should we package it?

Since client side code can be modified and it needs to be packaged and sent to client, how do we achieve this, so that client should not modify it, or if he does, we could track it somehow.

Comment: How about building docker image and deploying that? A docker image would only contain the application dist files. You can use nginx image to serve dist files.

Comment: That is also a slight issue, could there be some way where if client tries to modify the dist, we somehow get to know